# Difference between learning_curve and validation_curve

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, model-evaluations

What is the difference between these two curves: [learning_curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html) and [validation_curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve.html) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both curves show the training and validation scores of an estimator on the *y*-axis.

A learning curve plots the score over varying numbers of training samples, while a validation curve plots the score over a varying hyper parameter.

The learning curve is a tool for finding out if an estimator would benefit from more data, or if the model is too simple (biased).

[image]

Above example shows the training curve for a classifier where training and validation scores converge to a low value. This classifier would hardly benefit from adding more training data; a more expressive model may be more appropriate.

The validation curve is a tool for finding good hyper parameter settings. Some hyper parameters (number of neurons in a neural network, maximum tree depth in a decision tree, amount of regularization, etc.) control the complexity of a model. We want the model to be complex enough to capture relevant information in the training data but not too complex to avoid overfitting.

[image]

Above example shows the validation curve over a support vector machine's gamma parameter. A too low value of gamma restricts the model too much; both, training and validation scores are very low. A high value of gamma causes overfitting: very good training score but low validation score. The optimal value is somewhere in the middle, where the curves do not diverge too much.

Image source: [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html)

Comment: Thank you, so in principle they are both the same, just with a different parameter on the x-axis...?

Comment: @Ben In principle, yes. You could even consider the number of training samples a hyper parameter (although more is usually (always?) better).

Comment: alright, thanks. I wonder why there are two different functions in sklearn then..  this confused me heavily. However, things move on :) Thx!

Comment: I have another question: What about the loss curve? (How) do I make use out of it? And in a regression task I do not have accuracy, so I only plot the loss curve?

Comment: You use the loss curve to select a good value for the parameter. Both curves are general over estimator type: *score* can be accuracy, r2-score, mean-squared-error, f1-score, whatever you choose...

Comment: I think my question was not specific enough: You can use validation_curve and learning_curve and also get the loss-values through the history object. Are these different things or do the first two make us of the latter?

Comment: Ah, I don't know that... never used these scikit-learn specific functions myself.

Comment: Instead? How do you work? I'm still a fresh beginner trying to find my comfort zone in ML :)

Comment: I write my own functions/scripts... not the most efficient approach but rather instructive ;)